# a Prioty Queue method returns the minimum value with simple decrements

Tags: java

I think i am missing something here but, just looking for a clarification.
i copied this right out of the textbook,doesn't seem to understand how a priority queue method above return the lowest element in an array based queue. How does just having '--nItems' allow that return the minimum?

```
public long remove{
 return queueArray[--nItems]; // remove minimum item
 }
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the `remove` function, if you consider that there must also be an `insert` function that's doing some sort of sorted insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove` is only one method of Priority Queue. The assumption here is the array is already sorted in descending order and thus, the last element is the lowest element. Therefore, to remove the lowest element, all you have to do is return the last element of the array and decrease the number of elements in array.

There should be a separate methods to build the Priority Queue. 
i.e sort the elements in the array in descending order.